# inserting specific elements in different fileds of table

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

My Jquery code

```
 $("#cmdSubmit").click(function () {
    var cnt = 0;
    var ccc = [];

    $('input[type=date]').each(function (index, element) {
        ccc.push($(element).val());
        cnt++;
    });
    ccc = ccc.join(',');
});
```

This is my Jquery code where I am getting all the dates in PHP page and I have table name date_breaks where it has fields like id(autoinc field),`load_date,unload_date` and there are max 6 dates like `01-02-2013,12-02-2014, 07-02-2014,09-02-2014,10-02-2014,13-03-2014`.

If there are 6 dates I have to loop in 3 times such that firstdate must insert in load_date field and second date should insert in unload_date field and again third date in load_date field fourth date in unload_date field and so on for 5th and 6th

.if there are 4 dates I have to loop in 2 times such that firstdate must insert in load_date field and second date should insert in unload_date field and so on for 3rd and 4th dates.

If there are 2 dates i have to loop in 1 time such that firstdate must insert in load_date field and second date should insert in unload_date field can any body help me how this can be done in PHP.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share the relevant html

Comment: whether the input fields have commons names like `load_date` and `unload_date` to separate them

Comment: @user3332758 why are you posting same question again with different heading.You have asked same question 40 minutes before here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086987/indexing-of-array-and-inserting-into-specified-column-in-mysql-table

Comment: i didnt get ans for that can u please help me

Comment: we are asking the details but you have not provided anything - then how could we help you even if we want to

Comment: @user3332758 check my answer. Also if you are not getting answer means your question does not fully explains the problem.So instead of posting again please try to answer the question asked by other to make them understand what you want.If you didnt answer then you will not get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic may help you (i do not know php syntex)
Consider you have "datelist" array

then

```
for(i=0, i<datelist.length, i=i+2)
  {
     load_date = datelist[i];
     unload_date = datelist[i+1];
  }
```

Comment: you have to use `i<datelist.length` instead of `i<=datelist.length`.

Answer (score 0):

create a hidden input in form like this

```
<input id="some_hidden_input_id" name="some_hidden_input_name" />
```

then set the value of var ccc to that hidden feild like this

```
$("#some_hidden_input_id").val(ccc);
```

Then

when form submits get value and insert like this

```
$dates = $_POST['some_hidden_input_name'];

$date = explode(",",$dates);

$size=sizeof($date);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");



for($i=0;$i<$size;$i=$i+2;)
{
  if($i-1 < $size)
   {
      if(!isset($date[$i+1]))
         $date[$i+1]="";
      $sql="insert into date_breaks(load_date,unload_date) values($date[$i],$date[$i+1]) ";
      $result22 = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```